# on click div get big and back to normal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a mini Qcm, when I click on an answer the check moves on the div on which I clicked

```js
const reps = document.getElementsByClassName('rep');
[].forEach.call(reps, function(rep) {
  $(rep).click(function() {
    if (!rep.querySelector('.check')) {
      [].forEach.call(reps, function(repToDel) {
        if (repToDel.querySelector('.check')) {
          repToDel.querySelector('.check').remove()
        }
      })
      $(rep).last().append('<div class="check"><object data="check.svg" width="20" > </object></div>')
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 5%;
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.question_title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.container_reps {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.rep {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 15%;
  min-width: 170px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dot_rep {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 7px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.text_rep {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.check {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="question_title">
    <p>Je suis une Question, quelle est votre reponse ?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container_reps">
    <div class="rep">
      <span class="dot_rep">A</span>
      <p class="text_rep">Reponse 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rep">
      <span class="dot_rep">B</span>
      <p class="text_rep">Reponse 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rep">
      <span class="dot_rep">C</span>
      <p class="text_rep">Reponse 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rep">
      <span class="dot_rep">D</span>
      <p class="text_rep">Reponse 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I click the div get big and back to normal at the same time,I tried the overflow:hidden, but it didn't work.
the change between the check must be done smoothly.

Comment: Sorry I would like to help you but when but when I try your code, nothing happens.

Comment: me when i try it, the div becaume big and back to normal

Comment: Sorry I spoke too quickly under Edge we indeed see a change in the height of the layer but on the other hand there is no display effect to know which answer has been checked...? But under Mozilla Firefox I don't see the change in the height of the div. Only under Edge.

Comment: why doase this probleme happen only in chrome??

Comment: I did new tests with the image I was missing (which I changed to check.png) and I have no layer change neither on Edge nor on Mozilla Firefox and everything works fine. I am putting my code in response with small code improvement and some comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this JQuery code and if the image is present it's works

```
$(function(){

 const reps = document.getElementsByClassName('rep');

    [].forEach.call(reps,function(rep){

        $(rep).click(function(){

        // Remove Check Div only for Old Check
        [].forEach.call(reps,function(repToDel) { if(repToDel.querySelector('.check'))  repToDel.querySelector('.check').remove(); });

        // Put Check Div for New Check
        if(! rep.querySelector('.check'))   $(rep).last().append('<div class="check"><object data="check.png" width="20" > </object></div>');
        
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: the same issue :(

Comment: I made test with this code, your HTML and your CSS. You can test [Here](http://lesphotosdejuan.fr/stackoverflow/quest/)

Comment: yes it's work here

Comment: So you can grab all the code from this page to test but then it should work for you. :)

Comment: The probleme was with the svg

Comment: I didn't have any svg available so I tested with a png. And let me make that clear in my comments.